# How to send a function definition to MathLink from C/C++?

Tags: functions, mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability

In [this tutorial](http://centra.ist.utl.pt/amaro/ML_Tut.pdf) some *MathLink* concepts are introduced. At page 33 in the last lines the author is talking about sending to *MathLink* a function definition like `F[x_] := x^2`.

In C/C++ (Unix) I want to to do exactly like that! Which function should I use to put a definition? `MLPutFunction`? `MLPutSymbol`?

Comment: The simplest way is to define the function in the `.tm` file.

Comment: You mean templates? But aren't they used to call a C prog from Mathematica? Here I want the opposite

Comment: Would you please show me an example?

Comment: Yes, template files are used when calling C functions from Mathematica.  You should make it clear in your question that you need the opposite.

Comment: Looking at your other MathLink questions: why don't you just drive your C program from Mathematica?  It would let you write the Mathematica part directly in Mathematica and would save you a lot of trouble.  Your C program can still call back to Mathematica when it needs to.  I suspect your design is needlessly complicated.  Also regarding your other question: you can just send commands as strings when that is actually simpler and the whole command is known beforehand.

Comment: @Szabolcs one reason to call Mathematica from C is if the C code already exists (and is kind of complicated to build/refactor).  I have a case now where I wish I could shoe horn in Mathematica's random number generators into the C program, and I would be off to the races.

Comment: @EricBrown There are certainly good uses for calling Mathematica from C.  I made that comment because at that time Andry has posted several related questions on the topic and after reading them I had the impression that for his application it *might* not really be necessary.  My comment doesn't apply to all situations.

Comment: @Eric Calling Mma's RNG from C is not difficult, but the performance hit (compared to an RNG implemented in C) is going to be very significant.

Comment: @Szabolcs  I haven't been able to figure out how to round trip from C (I will keep trying.)  Agreed, it will be a big performance hit over C or Fortran RNG, but if the RNG for exotic (or novel) distributions is not available, then Mathematica should be acceptable for an ad hoc RNG for development purposes.  (Of course you know this, just letting you know that I know :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 2.3.1 of the document you linked details how you can send things to the kernel.

The main point here is that *you can send a function definition like you send any other Mathematica input*.  I doesn't matter that it's a function definition.  It's just an expression like any other.  If you send as an expression, remember its full form: `SetDelayed[F[Pattern[x, Blank[]]], Power[x, 2]]`

You can send things to the kernel for evaluation in two ways: either as a string or as an expression.  Sending as a string is going to be far easier if you know beforehand what you want to send.

There are two ways to send something as string (shown in section 2.3.1 again):

```
MLPutFunction(link, "EvaluatePacket", 1);
MLPutFunction(link, "ToExpression", 1);
MLPutString(link, "...");
MLEndPacket(link);
```

or more directly:

```
MLPutFunction(link, "EnterTextPacket", 1);
MLPutString(link, "...");
MLEndPacket(link);
```

Comment: I was reading that document last night so many times that I didn't recognize that section... thankyou for your concern and your answer!